# appending image array not appending image same image twice

Tags: arrays, swift, image, append

My swift codes goal is to create a array of images appended from a tableview cell. The code works however if the image is repeated twice. Right now sc.jpg is repeated twice in the array somepics when the code is appended. What prints out is gwen.jpg, kids.jgp, and sc.jpg only once. I want sc.jpg to appear twice in the array just like how it is in array somepics.

```swift
  var arrayThatStartsEmpty = [UIImage]()
  
  var somePics: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "gwen.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "kids.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "sc.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "sc.jpg")!]
     
  @objc func collect(){
    let collect = (0..<arr.count).compactMap { (theTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)) as? customtv)?.pic }
    let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { $0.image }
    arrayThatStartsEmpty.append(contentsOf: arrayValues2)
    print(arrayValues2)
  }
```

Comment: what's `arr` inside `collect()`? is it` somePics`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes on your `collect()` method. You can give it a try

```
      @objc func collect(){
        let collect = arr.enumerated().compactMap { (index, _) in 
        (theTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? customtv)?.pic }
        let arrayValues2 = collect.compactMap { $0.image }
        arrayThatStartsEmpty.append(contentsOf: arrayValues2)
        print(arrayValues2)
      }
```